# How does a function's arguments get values when it is instantiated as an object?

Tags: javascript, oop, function, arguments

So, this is my function:

```
function thisismyfunction(myvariable) {
  // I do stuff here
}
```

And then if I wanted to run it, I'd assume something similar to this:

```
thisismyfunction('foo');
```

And then the argument is given. But what if it was something like this:

```
var myobject = new thisismyfunction;
```

Then how would the argument by given?

**UPDATE:** It seems that it is possible to instantiate it like this:

```
var myobject = new thisismyfunction('foo');
```

But is there another way which still can pass the value in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `new` then the parenthesis are optional so long as you aren't passing arguments.

If you want arguments (that are not `undefined`), then they are required.

```
var myobject = new thisismyconstructor('foo');
```

---

Re follow up question:

> It seems that it is possible to instantiate it like this:

Of course. I just said that.

> But is there another way which still can pass the value in?

There isn't any need for another way.

Comment: Does that mean it implicitly creates a default ctor? I was thinking of two options, it implicitly passes null or creates a default ctor.

Comment: It *is* a constructor. It doesn't implicitly pass null, all arguments that are unspecified are `undefined` (whether or not `new` is used). `new` just lets you omit the `()` if you aren't passing any arguments.

Comment: @Quentin although jslint will probably complain about it if you miss the `()`

Comment: @elclanrs — Yes, Douglas Crockford considers it less than best practise to do so (and I agree with that), the language allows it though.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually giving the argument and it happens to be "undefined".

Comment: what I mean is that: var myobject=new thisismyfunction corresponds to var myobject=new thisismyfunction(undefined)

Comment: also very useful, could be better with an explanation and demo though.